# DKeras missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to use DKeras, but when I use this

```
 model = dKeras(model=brain.model, init_ray=False, wait_for_workers=True, n_workers=2)
```

Through this error

```
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
```

The model is really simple and is working without dKeras

```
    states = keras.Input(shape=(616,))
  
    a = Dense(units=128, activation='sigmoid')(states)
    a = Dropout(rate=0.1)(a)

    x = Dense(units = 64, activation = 'sigmoid')(a)
    x = Dropout(rate = 0.1)(x)

    y = Dense(units = 32, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
    y = Dropout(rate = 0.1)(y)

    q_values = Dense(units = number_actions, activation = 'softmax')(y)
    
    self.model = Model(inputs = states, outputs = q_values)
    self.model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = Adam(lr = learning_rate))
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve ? I'm trying to use dkeras with a custom model with no luck..